# System.java:-2:in `arraycopy': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, rubygems, jruby

I'm trying to install a gem using jruby but am not having any luck.

scoutradio@strawberry:~/scott$ sudo jruby --1.8 -S gem install diarize-jruby

I get the following and have searched all over the interweb without much luck. Can anyone shed any light on how to 'fix' this error? Looking around it's not code specific - But I cant find the solution to fix it.

```
scoutradio@strawberry:~/scott$ sudo jruby --1.8 -S gem install diarize-jruby
JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
System.java:-2:in `arraycopy': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        from DefaultResolver.java:111:in `makeTime'
        from DefaultResolver.java:277:in `create'
        from DefaultResolver.java:317:in `handleScalar'
        from DefaultResolver.java:435:in `orgHandler'
        from DefaultResolver.java:455:in `node_import'
        from org/yecht/ruby/DefaultResolver$s_method_1_0$RUBYINVOKER$node_import.gen:65535:in `call'
        from CachingCallSite.java:146:in `call'
        from RubyLoadHandler.java:39:in `handle'
        from Parser.java:300:in `addNode'
        from DefaultYAMLParser.java:676:in `yyparse'
        from Parser.java:290:in `yechtparse'
        from Parser.java:284:in `parse'
        from YParser.java:152:in `load'
        from org/yecht/ruby/YParser$s_method_0_1$RUBYINVOKER$load.gen:65535:in `call'
        from JavaMethod.java:630:in `call'
        from DynamicMethod.java:186:in `call'
        from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JRUBY-5581](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5581) is a reported bug with a matching error message, fixed in JRuby 1.6.2.